# Insert missing rows (with zero values) into table, following a display pattern

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm creating a procedure that loops through the following table to create a report:

```
INSERT INTO temp_data
SELECT val_year, val_name, Group_A, Group_B, Group_C, SUM(product_count) AS in_stock
FROM all_products
GROUP BY val_year, val_name, Group_A, Group_B, Group_C;

Resulting rows:
1: 2014, product_a, food, hot, delicious, 50
2: 2014, product_a, food, hot, fast, 30
3: 2014, product_a, food, cold, delicious, 10
4: 2014, product_a, drinks, hot, delicious, 20
5: 2014, product_a, drinks, cold, delicious, 40
6: 2014, product_a, drinks, cold, fast, 60

7: 2014, product_b, food, hot, delicious, 70
... etc.
```

The table all_products has been previously created through various UNION ALL queries etc.

I need to report these results to my superiors now, but the table looks like it has "missing" values. I need to rebuild that table so that it shows missing groups with a zero value.

I need to display all the values in a certain pattern, this example would be my desired display:

```
Rows:
1: 2014, product_a, food, hot, delicious, 50
2: 2014, product_a, food, hot, fast, 30
3: 2014, product_a, food, cold, delicious, 10
4: 2014, product_a, food, cold, fast, 0
5: 2014, product_a, drinks, hot, delicious, 20
6: 2014, product_a, drinks, hot, fast, 0
7: 2014, product_a, drinks, cold, delicious, 40
8: 2014, product_a, drinks, cold, fast, 60

9: 2014, product_b, food, hot, delicious, 70
... etc.
```

Notice row 4 and 6 have been filled to display zero values for products that are not in stock.

Is there any easy (quick) way to fill the missing rows? All I could think of was a huge 200+ lines long FOR LOOP that goes through current groups, checks for group changes and appends missing groups on group change. That approach felt kind of unprofessional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by generating all the rows first (using a `cross join`) and then bringing in the values:

```
select y.val_year, g.val_name, g.Group_A, g.Group_B, g.Group_C,
       coalesce(in_stock, 0) as in_stock
from (select distinct val_year from temp_data) y cross join
     (select distinct val_name, Group_A, Group_B, Group_C from temp_data) g left join
     temp_data d
     on d.val_year = y.val_year and
        d.val_name = g.val_name and
        d.Group_A = g.Group_A and
        d.Group_B = g.Group_B and
        d.Group_C = g.Group_C;
```

You could also do this directly on `all_products`.  For instance, you could add the CTE to the above query:

```
with temp_data as (
      SELECT val_year, val_name, Group_A, Group_B, Group_C, SUM(product_count) AS in_stock
      FROM all_products
      GROUP BY val_year, val_name, Group_A, Group_B, Group_C
     )
```

Comment: Thanks you sir.

Anyone looking for in depth info on the solution, I just found something extra here:
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2005/09/12/7755.aspx